# Q3DSurface selected point signal

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QtDataVisualization ([Q3DSurface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html) in particular) to make a simple 3D surface graph.

The Q3DSurface supports selection of a point on the graph by showing a highlighted ball on the data point where the user has clicked. The selection pointer shows the coordinates of the point. It looks like this: [surface with selected point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0vi7.png)

However, I'm not able to find a signal that is emitted when the selection happens. Having read through the documentation of [Q3DSurface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/q3dsurface.html) and [QSurface3DSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsurface3dseries.html), I failed to find any corresponding signal. There is only a `selectedPointChanged(const QPoint &position)` in QSurface3DSeries, but it operates with a two-dimensional QPoint which is not suitable for the case.

What I am trying to do is store a history of selected points, that is why I need such a signal to keep track of previous coordinates. I tried looking into implementing a custom Q3DInputHandler, but not sure that it can resolve the issue. I would be grateful for any advice on the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired signal is `itemLabelChanged(const QString &label)` in [QAbstract3DSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstract3dseries.html)

It is emitted when a label, which represents the chosen point's coordinates, is changed. By connecting this signal to the slot, it is possible to retrieve the label's text (`const QString &label` parameter).

Answer (score 0):

A good solution can be found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/114806/q3dsurface-selected-point-signal/2)

Briefly, it is possible to get the 3D position by using `const QSurfaceDataItem *QSurfaceDataProxy::itemAt(const QPoint &position)` being `position` the value provided by the `QAbstract3DGraph` signal `selectedElementChanged(QAbstract3DGraph::ElementType type)`.

For example:

```
Q3DSurface* surface = new Q3DSurface();
surface->setSelectionMode(QAbstract3DGraph::SelectionRowAndColumn);

QSurface3DSeries* surfaceSeries = new QSurface3DSeries();
surfaceSeries->dataProxy()->resetArray(dataArray); // QSurfaceDataArray* dataArray containing the surface data
surface->addSeries(surfaceSeries);

QObject::connect(surfaceSeries, &QSurface3DSeries::selectedPointChanged, this, [surfaceSeries](const QPoint &pos)
    {
        if ((pos.x() >= 0) && (pos.y() >= 0)) {
            QVector3D vector = surfaceSeries->dataProxy()->itemAt(pos)->position();
            qDebug() << vector;
        }
    });
```